# Magento 2: Promotion percentage off, but only upto a fixed amount

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions

I want to make a rule where I offer my customers a discount of:

> 50% on their whole cart, but the max discount amount is
>   fixed to 20$.

Can I make this in Magento 2, using one or a couple of rules?

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Please make a cart price rule from Admin > Marketing > Cart Price Rules, set condition and action as shown in following screenshots:
[image]

[image]

After creating rule, please add new schedule for it. I hope this may helpful to you!!